# How to ignore Syntax Errors due to invalid token in the returned JSON in geocoding

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, syntax-error, httpresponse

I am sending a query to geocoding with state/country and getting a list of JSON responses. Sometimes the JSON doesn't get parsed properly. How can I ignore such result and just move on to the next one?

Here is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/abc/points",
    context: document.body,
    data: {
        latitude: places[0].geometry.location
            .lat(),
        longitude: places[0].geometry.location
            .lng(),
        distance: $(
                'input[name="distance"]:checked')
            .val(),
        city: city1,
        state: state1,
        country: country1,

    },
    success: function(responseText) {
        $("#response-div").html(
            responseText);
        $("#response-div")
            .find("script")
            .each(
                function(i) {
                    eval($(
                            this)
                        .text());
                });
        $("html").removeClass(
            "wait");
    }

});
```

There are hundreds of results returned and I just want it to skip the ones that cause the syntax error and move on. I can post sample `JSON` text returned if you need it.

Thanks

**COMMENT**
Ok I was not able to find out if syntax errors can be ignored. So here is my next approach. Basically its a response that is getting parsed into JSON and its unable to ignore `\n` character in JSTL. I need to be able to replace `\n` as well as "," by "". Any help is appreciated. I know there are posts that explain how to ignore either of these, but not both at the same time.

```
function(marker, event, context) {
                             var contentString = '<div style="width:600px; height: 300px;">' +
                                                    '<div> <h4>' +  '${fn:replace(object.name, search, replace)}' + ' </h4> </div>' +
                                                    '<table class="table">' +
                                                      '<tbody>' +
                                                        '<tr class="active">' +
                                                          '<td>Address: </td>' +
                                                          <c:set var="address" value="${object.stAddress} ${object.city}, ${object.state} ${object.zipcode}" />
                                                          '<td colspan=5>' + "${fn:replace(address, ",", " ")}"+"${fn:replace(address, "\n", " ")}" + '</td>' +
                                                       ' </tr>' +
```

**Edit** 
I have tried this and although it works to replace some other characters it fails to work for `\n`

```
<c:set var="search" value="'" />
<c:set var="replace" value="" />
<c:set var="newLn" value="\n" />
${fn:replace(fn:replace(address, newLn, replace), search, replace)}
```

Comment: Maybe wrap the eval line in a `try...catch`?

Comment: What JSON? Nothing in that code you've shared appears to have anything to do with JSON. If the server was returning an `application/json` content-type then jQuery would parse it automatically and `responseText` would be (probably) an object so it wouldn't make sense to pass it to the `html()` method.

Comment: Is the `eval` statement what you are talking about? **NEVER USE EVAL FOR PARSING JSON**. We've had a proper, faster, easier to use, easier to debug, JSON parser [built into browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for **years**.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable. You don't have enough indentation on the first line to trigger *code* formatting, but the rest is massively indented so there is a high amount of useless whitespace on the left and a horizontal scroll bar! There are plenty of code tidying tools out there that you could use.

Comment: @yuriy636 I was thinking along these lines as well. But what would you put in the catch so that it just bypasses the error and continues processing the other results?

Comment: @Quentin : I haven't posted the returned JSON but as I mentioned that I can if needed. The response returned is in JSON. 
The code isn't written by me. Its a very old code that I am just making some adjustments to.

Comment: Can syntax errors even be ignored? I am beginning to think not!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to figure this out. Putting my solution here in case it helps anyone.

```
<c:set var="modAdd" value="${fn:replace(origAdd,newLn, "")}" />
```

Now in my code I just used this variable to perform double replacements.

```
${fn:replace(modAdd, "'", "")}
```